# NumberPicker freezes app when changing visibility or height while scrolling

Tags: android, android-number-picker

I am working on an app and I have a layout with items that when pressed, reveal a NumberPicker below them, like this:

[image]

I am using the native Android NumberPicker. The NumberPickers start with visibility `GONE` and their visibility is toggled when pressing the item above them. However, I have discovered that if the user attempts to close a picker in this way when it is still scrolling (for example a hard swipe on the picker and then immediately press the item to close that picker while it's still scrolling) causes the picker to get stuck in an infinite loop, freezing and eventually crashing the app. Logging the `onValueChangedListener` for the NumberPicker reveals these logs:

```
2020-03-25 16:13:39.545 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 4
2020-03-25 16:13:39.545 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 5
2020-03-25 16:13:39.545 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 6
2020-03-25 16:13:39.545 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 7
2020-03-25 16:13:39.558 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug W/View: requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.NumberPicker$CustomEditText{f549769 IFED..CL. ......I. 0,0-1080,10 #1020386 android:id/numberpicker_input} during layout: running second layout pass
2020-03-25 16:13:39.560 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 6
2020-03-25 16:13:39.561 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 5
2020-03-25 16:13:39.561 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 4
2020-03-25 16:13:39.561 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 3
2020-03-25 16:13:39.561 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 2
2020-03-25 16:13:39.561 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 1
2020-03-25 16:13:39.561 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 0
2020-03-25 16:13:39.569 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/chatty: uid=10345(com.example.expandablepicker.debug) identical 283 lines
2020-03-25 16:13:39.569 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 0
2020-03-25 16:13:39.569 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 0
2020-03-25 16:13:39.569 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/ExpandingPickerItem: value change, 0
2020-03-25 16:13:39.572 30393-30393/com.example.expandablepicker.debug I/chatty: uid=10345(com.example.expandablepicker.debug) identical 93 lines
```

I have also implemented a version of this where the visibility change of the NumberPicker is animated, so it expands out and in instead of just being revealed. I implemented this with an Animation that changed the height of the NumberPicker. When this is the case, the picker ends up stalling about halfway through the closing animation, in the same way as it stalls with changing the visibility.

I have tried a couple of different things to halt the scrolling of the NumberPicker before I try to close it. None so far have worked. I have tried (in no particular order)

- calling `setValue` to the last known value of the NumberPicker, thinking that might just halt the scroll
- calling `setEnabled(false)` before hiding the NumberPicker
- calling `performClick()` before hiding the NumberPicker
- calling `dispatchTouchEvent(...)` before hiding the NumberPicker
- calling `jumpDrawablesToCurrentState()` on the NumberPicker and its parent view
- calling `scrollBy(0, 0)` before hiding the NumberPicker

In all cases the scroll animation continued unaffected, and the app would freeze when trying to hide the picker.

Is there any way I can halt the scroll of the NumberPicker so that I can hide the view without this looping problem? Or maybe there is a way to safely hide and reveal pickers without causing them to loop in this way?

Thanks

Comment: can you share the code , highlighting the lines of error

Comment: Hi, do you have any success on this? Having the same issue when targeting Android 10